# How to get values from Gridview column

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an editable GridView that emails it's content to all companies. The first row of the Gridview contains the company name (just 1 name per row). I want to email the Gridview to a specific email address based off of the company name in the first row. e.g - if first row equals companyname1 then send the email to company one; if first row equal company two, then send the email to company two. I attempted the following:

//C# - code snippet behind button

```
foreach (GridView item in gvCompanies.Rows)
        {
            if (item.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text == "company1")
            {
                txtEmailAddresses.Text = "company1@gmail.com";
            }
            else if (item.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text == "company2")
            {
                txtEmailAddresses.Text = "company2.com";
            }

            else if (item.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text == "company3")
            {
                txtEmailAddresses.Text = "company3@aol.com";
            }

            else if (item.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text == "company4")
            {
                txtEmailAddresses.Text = "company@aol.com";
            }
        }
```

...Could anyone provide some guidance as to what am doing wrong here?

Comment: ...correction previous post, the second row contains the company name, the first row is the edit link.

Comment: What does work, what doesn't? Have you stepped through the code with a debugger to see where the error is? My guess is that you only look at SelectedRows and thus get unexpected behaviour from the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this...

```
protected void gvCompanies_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //for (int i = 0; i < gvCompanies.Rows.Count; i++)
 //       {
            if (gvCompanies.SelectedIndex == i)
            {
                String compName = gvCompanies.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text; //Gets the data cell value from the grid to string
                if(compName == "company1")
                {
                txtEmailAddresses.Text = "company1@gmail.com";
                }
                else if(compName == "company2")
                {
                txtEmailAddresses.Text = "company2@gmail.com";
                }
                ........and so on
            }
      // }
}
```

You need to set the folowing 2 properties of gridview.

1] `AutoGenerateSelectButton="true"` and
2] `onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"`.

Comment: The only issue am running into is the "txtEmailAddresses.Text" (textbox control)  is not picking up the email address as stated in the conditional statement provided above. My first column has the edit url link (works well) then my next column contains the company name, so I have gvCompanies.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text set to read the second row, but still nothing appears in the textbox. Now when I type the email into the Textbox control, & hit send button, it works. Am trying to figure out why the textbox control is not picking up the email address as instructed in the conditional statement above.

Comment: I think I've found my problem - I will check back shortly w/ status